# SQL Date Between Time Not Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

Using this date format: `mm/dd/yyyy h:m AM/PM` (example: `06/05/2014 5:00 PM`), how can I ignore the actual date and grab a count of data between specific times? (e.g. 5pm-9pm)

I tried something like this, but of course it didn't work and I'm not sure if SQL can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mobile_statistics WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '5:00 PM' AND '9:00 PM';
```

Notes: the timestamp field is type `nvarchar(MAX)`

Comment: Not related, but I'd strongly suggest changing your datatype from `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `DATETIME2` (or just DATETIME). It can cause all kinds of conversion errors, is more storage and requires more work in queries to convert, both implicitly and explicitly. Further reading - [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @GarethD yeah I didn't have control over the data type unfortunately. I do know better though, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the datetime to a `time`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM mobile_statistics 
WHERE CAST(timestamp AS time) BETWEEN '5:00 PM' AND '9:00 PM';
```

Comment: So, I have 349,226 rows in my database. This query returned a count of  68554 rows, but the inverse (9:00PM -> 5:00AM) returns 0 rows (which is wrong). How does SQL know to ignore the dates before the time?

Comment: @RUJordan how exactly did you code the inverse? You can't say `> 9 PM AND < 5 AM` - 0 rows will match that. You need `< 5 AM OR > 9 PM`.

Comment: @RUJordan: you can get the inverse by simply using the `not` operator:  `where convert(time,timestamp) NOT between '17:00' AND '21:00'` should do you. Any `null` values will fail both tests as `null` fails all tests save for explicit tests for nullity via `is [not] null`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, simply use `convert()` to convert your string to a `time` datatype. Then you can use  *discriminant functions* to count things in buckets. Something like

```
select within_business_hours  = sum(case when convert(time,timestamp))     between '17:00' and '21:00' then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       outside_business_hours = sum(case when convert(time,timestamp)) not between '17:00' and '21:00' then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       null_values            = sum(case when timestamp is null                                        then 1 else 0 end ) ,
from dbo.mobile_statistics ms
```

should give you

- the count of rows with the timestamp within business hours
- the count of rows with the timestamp outside business hours
- the count of rows with a `null` timestamp

The sum of which should match the total number of rows.